# Proof in Algebraic Topology without appeal to intuition

Tags: algebraic-topology, alternative-proof, proof-explanation

My question arose from the proof of proposition 1.26 in Hatchers Algebraic Topology. There he constructs a space $Z$ from a path-connected space $X$ as follows:

1. attach a set of 2-cells $e_\alpha$ via maps $\varphi_\alpha : S^1 \rightarrow X$
2. choose a basepoint $x_0$ in $X$ and paths $\gamma_\alpha$ from $x_0$ to $\varphi_\alpha(s_0)$ (where $s_0$ is an arbitrary point in $S^1$), then
3. for each $\alpha$ take a rectangular strip $S_\alpha = [0,1] \times [0,1]$ and attach one of its edges to $X$ via $\gamma_\alpha$, and the adjacent edge at $\varphi_\alpha(s_0)$ to an arc in $e_\alpha$
4. finally glue these strips together along their edges opposite to the ones attached to the $e_\alpha$

There is a picture in the book on page 50.

Now Hatcher claims that

1. $Z - X$ is contractible and
2. the space obtained from $Z$ by removing one interior point from each $e_\alpha - S_\alpha$ deformation retracts onto $X$

Intuitively this seems quite straightforward, but a detailed proof would get quite messy. That is, unless there is an elegant way of modularizing.

And this is my question: how to prove 1. and 2. elegantly without relying on intuition?

I would also be grateful for references if someone can recommend a book about Algebraic Topology which relies less on intuition.

Comment: One might also consider ignoring elegance, embracing messiness, and asking how to prove 1 and 2 rigorously, using ones intuition as a guide to writing down actual formulas of functions and homotopies which are witnesses to contractibility, to deformation retractions, and whatever is needed. Being able to write down these formulas when needed is an essential skill.

Comment: One book which takes this point of view is Whiteheads "Elements of homotopy theory".

Comment: @Lee I have followed your advice and you are right -- I learned by doing. I made heavy use of the fact that the constructions can be realized using pushout diagramms in the category of topological spaces.  I wonder whether that is the (or a) usual way to go or whether I am complicating things unnecessarily... the proof did get very long...

Comment: Many of these proofs, when the homotopies are written out in full, do indeed get long. Perhaps the key thing that happens, which seems kind of paradoxical, is that one eventually builds up and understands enough tools (proved rigorously) so that you can then let your intuition take over in a rigorous fashion.